# Android Navigation Component not maintaining stack on switching between tabs

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, navigation, android-bottomnavigationview

I have 3 bottom tabs and it used 3 different navigation graphs for each tab. When user play around and uses device back button then the back stack works fine like

1. Home inner fragment
2. Tap on middle tab say "browse"
3. Now back-press the user taken to "home" inner fragment

But when i use tabs to navigate then it always takes me to the landing fragment (initial fragment)

Need a solution like below blog Post

https://proandroiddev.com/fragments-swapping-with-bottom-bar-ffbd265bd742

Answer (score 0):

Seems this got resolved from Google, lets hope for the stable version sooner

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80029773